# IIS http 404 error url-redirecting via web.config makes many needless extra requests?

Tags: iis, web-config

With classic asp I try to redirect to a given page when server cannot find the requested page. However, I face strange extra-requests and responses when the first redirecting to the given page has taken place. For some reason there happens very many extra requests and responses to and from server.
Here is my simple web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
            <error statusCode="404" path="/folder/index.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
        </httpErrors>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Has anyone any idea why server continues with extra requests (some even 10 requests)?

Also, I noticed that css-file for the page takes no effect either. So, page html gets rendered without css-formation.

I also noticed that css gets rendered properly if target url has file-extension. But if url is extensionless, i.e. of the type "http://.../info/info2/222" then css does not get rendered even though 404-redirection happens (with very many extra requests / responses).

Comment: Do any of your pages contain tags with incorrect src attributes?

Comment: Yes, at the moment, that is true. Is this the cause for the issue?

Comment: I put proper images to links and that solved half of the issue - those extra calls disappeared indeed with proper links. But css rendering issue is still left if url is of the form "http://.../info/info2/rrr/". However, if the url does not have extra slashes (i.e. "/") then css get's properly rendered, i.e  "http://.../info/last" where "last" is file name without extension. But any extra slashes and further paths prevent css from rendering.

Comment: You own the code, then why not fix those missing items to eliminate the 404 errors? You shouldn't rely on any redirection.

Comment: Well, Lex Li, I already told that I put proper images and it fixed the issue, and I gave credits to the one who helped me to realize it. But there is another question also concerning the behavior of css. And I have a reason to ask that question, for I need that behavior, i.e. redirecting after the http 404 error, which works as such, but the question now is: why on the redirected asp-page, the css-file (linked normally in the head) is not working properly.

Comment: Some further info: I noticed that when I moved css code from the external file to style-tags in the redirected asp-page, the issue got solved and css takes properly effect. So, it has something to do with deficient loading of external css-file in the case of http 404 redirecting. Now with css in the style tags, it was possible to have any kind of (erroneous) url and page got properly rendered after 404-redirecting. Can anyone say why external css is not working and are there any fixes for it? For it is not good idea to move permanently much css code into the style-tags.

Comment: Also, I noticed in browser's network and console tools, that css-file cannot be found in 404-directing because the external css-file is added automatically to the end of erroneous url - i.e. for example: "http://.../info/info2/rrr/ddd/style.css". So, this is obviously what iis-server does by default. As a roundabout way, so far, I have found adding external css-file via the following: <style><!--#include file="css/styles.css"--></style> which might be the satisfying solution.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your custom errors in the Asp application use httpErrors instead of customError. So the problem is probably because of this.

When the server cannot find the requested page, httpErrors will determine the responding page based on the statuscode. The path of the page is /folder/index.asp, and the response mode is ExecuteURL. So /folder/index.asp is actually another request and response.

You didn't mention the original css file reference method, but the page is rendered without CSS. So I guess the additional request may be for the CSS file. You can view it from the development mode of the browser.

Comment: Bruce, I do not know the difference between the usage of httpErrors and customError. Could you, please, provide me an example, if they are related to the settings in the web.config.

Comment: If the error is caused by the .net code, custom error will be used to show error page. If the error is caused by IIS itself, httperror will be used to show error page.

Comment: Ok, that was a new piece of information to me. How could you suggest for me to change the web.config to make use of this information - if, in your view, you can see that there is a better way to solve the situation.

Comment: You need to make sure that you can directly access the error page through the url in the browser and the CSS can be loaded correctly.I don’t know what error you want to display the page for. If it is an asp application internal error such as YSOD, it is recommended to use custom error.